# How to make a list of pixels which intersect with my points?

Tags: qgis, raster, r, arcgis-pro, intersection

I have:

1. a series of rasters which are cut to the same dimensions with the same resolution (1km by 1 km).
2. I also have a series of points of bird observations.

I want to create a data frame which essentially tells the lat/long of each pixel in the raster, and provides a 1 for if there is q point in that raster and a 0 if there is no point in the raster.

I have access to QGIS, ARCGIS, & R, but would prefer to used ArcGIS, and thus am asking for solutions which use ArcGIS. In ArcGIS I’ve found raster to point let’s me create a list of coordinates for my pixels, but I haven’t found an intersect tool which tells me about intersects with individual pixels, rather than with the raster overall.

Comment: Please decide which of QGIS, ArcGIS Pro and R you wish to ask about in this particular question. If it’s R, PyQGIS or ArcPy then please include a code attempt.

Comment: QGIS: If you rasters arent very large you can vectorize them to create polygons, then spatial join the points to the polygons and then field calculate centroid coordinates